# Java pattern for displaying dynamic tables?

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, swt

I'm designing a Java application using SWT.  I have some tables which will display data from a database, just some relational rows with columns.  In some places I would like to display first and last name, then in other places I want to display full name, age, and salary. I even might want to display something like cartoon character names, what cartoon they are in, whether their a "good" character or a "bad" character, a ranking of how well known the character is, etc.

These are just examples to illustrate my point.  I want to display relational data, like exists in any database.  SWT has a table widget perfect for displaying this sort of data (as I expect most GUI libraries do), but the problem with my current design is I'm specifically attaching the columns I need to the table as I need them.  So in once places I'm attaching columns A,B,C then over here I'm attaching columns X,Y,Z.  What if I don't know exactly what my columns will look like before I receive the data?

Are there any patterns I might consider for moving the column information into the data itself?  I would guess this is a pretty common need.

I've thought of designing a container of Row objects (with an interface) with a method which returns a list of Strings, these Strings could be the title for the columns.  The Row objects could implement a method which returns the value of a given column, but each column might have a different type, so what exactly would I return? Also, it seems rather strange for the container to define the column names, then the Row objects in the container must define the other half of the desired behavior; it feels like all the required methods are spread across multiple interfaces.

So any design patterns or existing widgets I can look at would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you ask: "Are there any patterns I might consider for moving the column information into the data itself? I would guess this is a pretty common need."

It sounds like you want to construct a table to display some data you retrieve from a database, without "pre-defining" things like the number of columns / rows, the types of data in each column etc. Have you looked at the examples and tutorials on constructing a TableModel ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Once you fetch your data from the database, you would simply create an instance of a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). If you look at the constructors of DefaultTableModel, you'll notice that it can accept either a 2-d array of type Object (or a vector of vectors, or... you get the idea), which means you don't need to care about the "type" of the data. JTable will figure out how to best display the data based on what is in the model. Apologies ahead of time if I have totally misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Thank you.  The TableModal interface is close to what I am looking for.  Although it is not in SWT, I can still probably use it, or at least use the same ideas in my own interface.